# Compiling uwsgi from source for two different versions of python in emperor mode results in an error

Tags: uwsgi, gevent

I'm trying to configure uWSGI from source and make it compatible for two different versions of python. I also install the gevent plugin manually but with an error.

I do so by downloading the latest tarball and extracting from source as follows for each python version:

```
PYTHON=python2.7 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python27"
```

I also require the gevent plugin for both the python versions.

I try to obtain the plugin by the following command:

I tried general gevent:

```
./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/php"
```

For Gevent python3.4:

```
PYTHON=python3.4 uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/gevent/gevent gevent34"
```

However, when I run the uwsgi server, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/uwsgi/gevent_plugin.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_AsLong
```

I couldn't find anything to help online, it seems to be an obscure error and i'm really stuck on this.

Any advice on how to fix this?